# Capture powershell output from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to run this C# code:

```
Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
rs.Open();
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = rs;
ps.AddScript("Write-Output Hello | Out-File -FilePath myfile.txt");
ps.Invoke();
```

myfile.txt should contain Hello but the file does not exist. How can i redirect powershell commands standard output (and errors) ?

Thanks

*** EDIT ***

I have understood the problem: The Invoke command is not a blocking-command. So when Invoke() has finished, my file.txt does not exist yet.

Is there a way to wait for powershelgl script ending ? Thanks

Comment: Have you try using ps.AddCommand instead of ps.AddScript ?

Comment: Does that answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015157/how-do-i-redirect-output-from-powershell

Comment: I've run your code and it works fine for me (console app NET Framework 4.7). Where are you looking for the file? It should be created where your exe file is located. Also check if execution policy is set correctly (unrestricted).

Comment: In fact I need to wait script execution end. But how can I do that ? Thanks

Comment: `Invoke` blocks the thread already.

Answer (score 1):

> I have understood the problem: The Invoke command is not a blocking-command. So when Invoke() has finished, my file.txt does not exist yet.

You've *misunderstood* the problem, `Invoke()` is a synchronous method.

You haven't specified a location in which to operate (eg. `cd C:\some\path\` in the PowerShell script), so PowerShell will use the working directory of the hosting process as it's default location. The file will be written to the directory from which you launched your application, or the root of your user profile if you launched the application from the shell in Windows.

---

If you want to consume the output in your C# application, iterate over the return value from `Invoke()` instead:

```
Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
rs.Open();
PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = rs;
ps.AddScript("Write-Output Hello");

foreach (var outputItem in ps.Invoke()) {
  if (ps.HadErrors) {
    Console.WriteLine("Errors encountered!")
    foreach (var errorRecord in ps.Streams.Error) {
      Console.WriteLine(errorRecord);
      Console.WriteLine(errorRecord.ScriptStackTrace);
    }
    break;
  }
  Console.WriteLine(outputItem.BaseObject); // this will print the string Hello
}
```

Comment: It does not display anything. 
I have also tried a script which takes time to execute. Your foreach look ends before scripts ending.

Is there a way to wait and test if script execution is finished ?

Comment: @Bob5421 most likely explanation is that an error is encountered - I've updated the sample code to show how you might inspect those

Comment: Thanks i have already tried and i see nothing. What output do you see ?

Comment: @Bob5421 I see [the string `Hello` written to my console](https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/8LqMkHSUHibj.png?o=1).

Comment: I was trying with Write-Host instead of Write-Output. With Write-Host I do not see any error and I do not see any hello message...

Comment: @Bob5421 That's because `Write-Host` _writes output straight to the host application_. You don't have [a host implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/custom-host-samples?view=powershell-7.3), so you can't really take advantage of that, the output just isn't consumed at all.

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way to catch Write-Host output ?

Comment: @Bob5421 If memory serves me right, Write-Host in PowerShell 7 uses the `Information` stream as intermediary transport, so you might find the data in `ps.Streams.Information`

Comment: I have no "Information" object in Streams. I have tried "Debug", "Error", "Warning" streams. I do not see Write-Host output... For some commands, I see this output: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Do you know how I can parse it ? Thanks